# Operator overloading in C++ "<<"

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I try to overload operator in C++, but I am having some difficulties.
This is what I have in my class:

```
ostream & operator <<(ostream & s)
 {
  s << w();
 return s;

}
 string w()
{
stringstream ss;
string str;
for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if (i==n-1)
    {
        ss<<tablica[i] << "x^" << i;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tablica[i]<eps && tablica[i]>-eps) ss <<"+" << +tablica[i]<< "x^" << i;
        else if (tablica[i]<eps)ss << tablica[i]<< "x^" << i;
        if(tablica[i]>eps) ss <<"+" << +tablica[i]<< "x^" << i;
    }

}
ss >> str;
return str;

}
```

I am trying to use this like this:

```
cout << p << endl;
```

Error: `no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << p`
Here is my whole code of program: http://codepad.org/xBijPMCp

Comment: The parameter for `operator <<` should be *the thing on the right*.

Comment: By the way, you're using the wrong form of `delete`. That's undefined behaviour. You're also not following the Rule of Three/Five, which also leads to undefined behaviour. Just use a vector instead of that wretched pointer and you won't even need the destructor any more. That's already shorter, cleaner, more exception-safe code, moreso when you factor in the other functions you should have, but don't.

Comment: Actually, scrolling down more, I just realized that's a base class. It should have a virtual destructor, though with a vector or something, it could be as simple as `~ClassName() = default;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An overloaded operator is invoked in one of two ways. Either as a member function, where `x op y;` is treated as `x.op(y);` or else a global, where `x op y;` becomes `op(x,y);`.

Note that when the operator is a member function, the left operand must be the one for which you overload the operator. In the case of inserting into a stream: `x << y;`, the left operand is the stream object, so to overload the operator as a member function, you'd have to do the overload as a member of the stream class.

Since modifying the stream classes is pretty much off-limits, your only real choice is to implement the overload as a global function. In this case, however, the function must take *two* parameters (one for the left operand, one for the right operand).

Therefore, an insertion operator nearly always needs a signature like:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, T const &t)
```

(where `T` is whatever type you're going to insert).

Answer (score 4):

`ostream & operator <<(ostream & s)` should be implemented in the relation to a particular class(to make it usefull), so signature should be

```
friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & s, const class_name &c);
```

Comment: Make it a `friend` if it's defined in a class, which I think is what's happening here.

Comment: @Drew Dormann yes, sure to be able to output info about a class it ought to have access to members of that class(then friend relation should be estimated) otherwise getters() can be enough

Comment: @gongzhitaao thanks for edit. It is important to mention when dealing with complex objects which creation can be very consuming( time/memory ) operation better to use pass by reference over pass by value.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading is the ability to tell the compiler how to perform a certain operation when its corresponding operator is used on one or more variables.

For example, the compiler acts differently with regards to the subtraction operator `-` depending on how the operator is being used.

- When it is placed on the left of a numeric value such as -48, the compiler considers the number a negative value.
- When used between two integral values, such as 80-712, the compiler applies the subtraction operation.
- When used between an integer and a double-precision number, such as 558-9.27, the compiler subtracts the left number from the right number; the operation produces a double-precision number.
- When the `-` symbol is doubled up and placed on one side of a variable, such as `--Variable` or `Variable--`, the value of the variable needs to be decremented; in other words, the value 1 shall be subtracted from it.

All of these operations work because the subtraction operator `-` has been reconfigured in various classes to act appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to think about your general design. 
I think you want to overload `<<` to work with the type of your variable `tablica`. The `operator<<()` is a binary operator: the declaration have to be of the form:
`<<(Type t1, Type t2).` (is you want it to be a member this will "degenarte" to only one parametr, because the first-the left, will be a kind of `this`). In your case something like:

```
ostream & operator <<(ostream & s, const tablica_type &c);
```

Your tablica is a global variable, and n too, with normaly is not a good idea. You will probably want to define a class woth hold the tablica and the n, and for this class override <<().